# Best method for search into file

Tags: java, algorithm, file, search

I have a file with text like this:

```
4 abiogenezele
5 abiogenezelor
6 acefaliile
7 acefaliilor
8 acetonuriile
....
```

It have the format (ID_WORD WORD) and have an aproxim. ~33000 words.

I want for input a word to find his ID.

I try this code. It work but is not efficient.

```
int ID;
String word = "acefaliile";
String pattern = "(?i)([\\d]+) ("+word+")";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
boolean found = false;

// Read the file
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./resources/txt/lemma.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

        if (m.find( )) {
            // m.group(1) is ID
            // m.group(2) is WORD
            ID = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
            found=true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!found) {
        ID = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a database, something like `sqlite` may be ideal. Or just load them in memory.

Comment: Load the file into memory and perform a binary search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Load the file in memory.
- Divide lines by the space (the first space, if 'words' can contain spaces)
- Load data into map (dictionary) data structure (HashMap in Java?) with word as key and id as value.
- Do searches in this map.

Alternative way - put these key/value pairs in array or list, sort it, and use binary search.

Comment: It does not take up much memory ? There are 33,000 lines

Comment: It takes less than 1 megabyte of memory (depending on overall word length), but accelerates searches a hundred times

Comment: For your "alternative way," I think the sorting is unnecessary.  From the 5 lines that @AdrianSimionescu posted, it looks like the words are already sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @Jeff Irwin Yes, you are almost certainly right, but it has not been claimed clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lookeen as [file search](https://lookeen.com/index.html) program! This tool automatically searches in the content of files and you have a lot of filtering options.

Disclaimer: I work for the developer of Lookeen.